# No value passed for parameter

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

> I use kotli. I define everything  as per requirement, why I am getting
> thing type of Issue

```
UserRegistrationService.kt: (25, 36): No value passed for parameter 'userRegistration'
```

> I got this type of issue at my UserRegistration class No value passed
> for parameter department, and userRegistration
>
> I Creat ResponseTemplateVO POJO Class
> ResponseVO.kt

package com.userservice.userregistration.VO

```
import com.userservice.userregistration.entity.UserRegistration

data class ResponseTemplateVO(
    var userRegistration: UserRegistration,
    var department: Department
)
```

> Department.kt

```
package com.userservice.userregistration.VO

data class Department(
    val departmentId:Long=-1,
    val departmentName:String="",
    val departmentAddress:String="",
    val departmentCode:String=""
)
```

> UserRegistration.kt

```
package com.userservice.userregistration.entity
data class UserRegistration(
    val userId:Long=-1,
    val firstName:String="",
    val lastName:String="",
    val email:String="",
    val departmentId:Long=-1,
)
```

> UserRegistrationService.kt

```
package com.userservice.userregistration.service

import com.userservice.userregistration.VO.Department
import com.userservice.userregistration.VO.ResponseTemplateVO
import com.userservice.userregistration.entity.UserRegistration
import com.userservice.userregistration.repository.UserRegistrationRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate


@Service
class UserRegistrationService {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRegistrationRepository: UserRegistrationRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var restTemplate: RestTemplate

    fun saveUserDetails(userRegistration: UserRegistration): UserRegistration {
         return userRegistrationRepository.save(userRegistration)
    }

    fun getUserWithDepartment(userId: Long): ResponseTemplateVO {
        val vo= ResponseTemplateVO()
        val userRegistration:UserRegistration=userRegistrationRepository.findUserById(userId)
        val department: Department? =
            restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9001/departments/"+userRegistration.departmentId,
            Department::class.java)
        vo.userRegistration=userRegistration
        if (department != null) {
            vo.department=department
        }
        return vo

    }
}
```

> I am getting error at this below method at the line 2

```
val vo= ResponseTemplateVO()
```

> No value passed for parameter department and userRegistration .This is
> the error

```
fun getUserWithDepartment(userId: Long): ResponseTemplateVO {
        val vo= ResponseTemplateVO()
        val userRegistration:UserRegistration=userRegistrationRepository.findUserById(userId)
        val department: Department? =
            restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9001/departments/"+userRegistration.departmentId,
            Department::class.java)
        vo.userRegistration=userRegistration
        if (department != null) {
            vo.department=department
        }
        return vo

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the data class.

```
data class ResponseTemplateVO(
    var userRegistration: UserRegistration,
    var department: Department
)
```

Here you have added the following params into the constructor of the data class. Hence you will need to pass the values to the constructor of the class before you can initialise it.

Hence your ResponseTemplateVO data class will become like this

```
data class ResponseTemplateVO(
    var userRegistration: UserRegistration?=null,
    var department: Department?=null)
```

Now since we have already assigned null as the default value. Now you can initialise the data class and it creates the data class with the values set to null and you do not need to pass any value for params to the constructor. Now you can access each of the variables and set the respective data into them.

Comment: This is really not an approach I would advise first. Making things nullable should be avoided as much as possible. In particular, `userRegistration` doesn't have to be nullable in this case. Usually using `val` is also preferred over var because it allows smart casts etc., so this is also in favor of calling the constructor directly with the args instead of creating an empty object and filling it later.

Answer (score 3):

This declaration:

```kotlin
data class ResponseTemplateVO(
    var userRegistration: UserRegistration,
    var department: Department
)
```

packs multiple things:

- it declares 2 properties `userRegistration` and `department`
- it defines the primary constructor of the class with 2 arguments: `userRegistration` and `department`

When you write:

```kotlin
val vo = ResponseTemplateVO()
```

You're calling the constructor of that class, but you don't specify the 2 required arguments. You should instead call it by passing the arguments:

```kotlin
fun getUserWithDepartment(userId: Long): ResponseTemplateVO {
    val userRegistration:UserRegistration=userRegistrationRepository.findUserById(userId)
    val department: Department? = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9001/departments/"+userRegistration.departmentId,
            Department::class.java)
    if (department == null) {
        // here you should decide if it should have a default value
        // or throw an exception
    }
    return ResponseTemplateVO(userRegistration, department)
}
```

Note that you declared the `department` property as non-null, so you need a non-null department in order to create an instance of your class.
So if `department` is null you have 3 options:

1. throw an exception
2. use a default value instead
3. change the type of `department` in `ResponseTemplateVO` so it accepts nulls (`Department?` with `?`)

Also, if you instantiate your class with all required value like that, and you don't need to modify its properties later, the properties can be declared `val`. This is usually more idiomatic Kotlin. With immutability, it's easier to reason about the values.